# How to get random element in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 3 hero images and their content and I want to display them randomly when user refreshes the page!

Basically I am trying to display random div using Jquery on loading page, but issue is that the size of hero image is large and by using `Jquery`, all these 3 images start loading in `DOM` which affects the speed of page.

Is there any solution for this in Vue.js for loading that one specific `div` at a time, not all 3 `divs` when user refreshes the page!?

```
<div class="slider-item"> <img src="../../../static/img/slides/slide1.png" alt="Hello"> 
       <div class="carousel-caption"> 
           <h2>Lipsum Heading</h2> 
               <h4>Lipsum dummy content body test dummy goes here.</h4> 
       </div> 
   </div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
mounted()
{
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.slider-item').length);
 $('.slider-item').eq(random).show();
},
```

Comment: What are those images? Are they data URLs or just image links? And you are displaying only one image, not all three of them right?

Comment: @kevlai22 Yes, Want to show just one in DOM but randomly, this is HTML. 
<div class="slider-item">
                  <img src="../../../static/img/slides/slide1.png" alt="Hello">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h2>Lipsum Heading</h2>
                      <h4>Lipsum dummy content body test dummy goes here.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is pretty straight forward. Just randomize the link you've chosen in Vue.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    images: [
      'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/200x140',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/200x100'
    ],
    selectedImage: ''
  },
  created () {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
    this.selectedImage = this.images[idx]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img v-bind:src="selectedImage" />
</div>
```

Comment: Small thing about this: data needs to be a function. That is, it should be: 
`data() { return {} }`

Comment: In components, yes, in the code above, it's not necessary.

Comment: Good pt, missed that @kevguy

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

**html**

```
<div id="hero-bg">
    <img :src="currentBgPath">
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#hero-bg',
    data:{
        heroBgPaths: [
            '../path/to/img1',
            '../path/to/img2',
            '../path/to/img3'
        ],
        currentBgPath: null
    },
    created(){

        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.heroBgPaths.length);
        this.currentBgPath = this.heroBgPaths[random];
    }
})
```

- initialize the paths to your images as an array in your data property
- initialize a data property `currentBgPath` and set to to null
- in created life cycle hook get a random number within the number of items in your image paths array using

  ```
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.heroBgPaths.length);
  ```
- set the value of `currentBgPath` using `this.currentBgPath = this.heroBgPaths[random];` and bind the `src` attribite of the img element to `currentBgPath`